# Kohana/PHP records getting replaced if it is run inside the loop

Tags: php, kohana-3

I have the following snippet in my code, but the problem is when i try to add multiple items. it  is getting added but it is repalcing the previously added row , eg:- in the following code snippet only one record will be there for the id 150, and that record will be 13. can you please tell me what the problem is.

```
    public function StoreSkills($skills,$id) {
    $skills = "16,13";
    $id = "150";
    if(!empty($skills)){
        $UserSkillsObj = ORM::factory('userskill');
    $userskills = explode(',',$skills);
    foreach($userskills as $skill)
    {   
        //   $UserSkillsObj = ORM::factory('userskill'); if this statement is here,  
                                                //records are getting added just fine.
        $UserSkillsObj->user_id = $id;
        $UserSkillsObj->skills_id = $skill;
        $ids = $UserSkillsObj->save();


    }
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Move the line that creates the object to within your foreach loop. Having it outside means that you're always referencing the same object, therefore the final (second) loop saves over the first one, making it always 13.

Example:

```
foreach($userskills as $skill)
{   
    $UserSkillsObj = ORM::factory('userskill');
    $UserSkillsObj->user_id = $id;
    $UserSkillsObj->skills_id = $skill;
    $ids = $UserSkillsObj->save();
}
```